# Sql issue with selecting data

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 6 Tables.

```
Company  (1..1) --- (0..n) District
District (1..1) --- (0..n) City
City     (1..1) --- (0..n) Employee
```

So alot of 1 on n relation's to start off.

Then I have 1 n..n relation implemented like this:

```
Employee (1..1) --- (0..n) EmpLang
EmpLang  (0..n) --- (1..1) Lang
```

Now I select The employee like this:

```
SELECT Employee.Name, Employee.lastName, Employee.PhoneNumber
FROM Company, District, Employee, EmpLang, Lang

WHERE Company.id = District.cid
AND District.id = City.did
AND City.id = Employee.id
AND Company.name LIKE '{1}%'
AND District.name LIKE '{2}%'
AND City.name LIKE '{3}%'
```

`{1}, {2}, {3}`: Some random variables (not important)

My problem is I have another variable ( `{4}` ) wich is the language
filter.

- If it's empty I just want this query like above to be executed. (Or produce the same results at least.)
- If it has something in it:

  - I want to filter by looking for relationships in the last table (lang),

---

```
 ...
 AND City.name LIKE '{3}%'
 AND Employee.id = EmpLang.eid
 AND EmpLang.lid = Lang.id
 AND Lang.desc LIKE '{4}%'
```

- Also I don't want it to display the results twice if the person knows 2 lang's. So if the person knows English and Eduardian and the filter is 'e%' I only want to display the result once.

I would like to do this purely in mysql.

Comment: Please post some real sample data and a sample result. If the person knows > 1 `Lang`, but you only want one result, which one should it be?

Comment: Wel if the language filter is for example : 'e%' and the person knows English and Eduadrian I would just like it to reurn the SELECT Employee.name, Employee.lastName, Employee.phoneNumber once. Sadly I can't because I can't think of a way to write this code :(

Comment: Oh ok, then in your description above you should remove `EmpLang,Lang` from the `SELECT` list if you don't really want them in the results.

Comment: I understand that but don't I need them to link my other other sql statements too :o ? Honestly I have no clue and I am struggeling hours with this problem now :/

Comment: are you sure with this line `City.id = Employee.id`?

Comment: How are you passing in the values? Are they something like PHP variables, bound params?

Comment: The pattern for something like this is usually `AND (({4} IS NULL) OR ({4} IS NOT NULL AND Lang.desc LIKE '{4}%'))` so if it is null, no other condition is executed but if not null, additional conditions inside the right side of `OR` are evaluated.

Comment: So many pre ANSI 92 joins today I can't believe it. [Stop](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) doing things this way people.

Comment: Honestly why :/, I mean okay a new standerd and everything but I never needed to use it in 2 years so far. I diden't even knew what join did until now. And I converted his whole querie to a simple where, it's shorther and more clear  to read. Why force change on a system that works well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach it with a sub query.  In your where statement, you can do where employee.id in (select...)

the select statement here will select all employee_id's that meet that language.

```
where ...
and employeeid in (select employeeID 
from employee 
left join Emplang on Employee.id = EmpLang.eid 
left join land on  EmpLang.lid = Lang.id 
where Lang.desc LIKE '{4}%')
```

(I changed syntax on you, you are putting the joins in the where clause...it's older SQL, the join method I wrote here is easier to follow.

To handle the null language, wrap an or above the statement.

```
and (employee id in (select...) or 1 = case when {4} is null then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: Let me know if this makes sense, I'm hoping I use english gooder. ;)

Comment: Yes it did :). Sorry my english isen't so well it's mostly internet english xP.

Comment: I'd give you a +1 if you could post a version where you get rid of the old join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this instance you may want to look at doing a join.  You can learn more about joins if you are not familiar with them at this link: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

EDIT: I can't post the code now (at work) but if nobody else has responded by the time I get home I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: I have tried using a join, I litterally am spending hours now just staring at the screen I need sombody to post the code in here if possible.

Comment: @mkross1983 - he is using older syntax, the joins are being held in his where clause.

Comment: @mkross1983 You may not be aware of this fact since they did away with this style of `JOIN` 22 years ago!

Answer (score -2):

You should use a distinct in your query to only return the values once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee.Name, Employee.lastName, Employee.PhoneNumber
FROM Company, District, Employee, EmpLang, Lang

WHERE Company.id = District.cid
AND District.id = City.did
AND City.id = Employee.id
AND Company.name LIKE '{1}%'
AND District.name LIKE '{2}%'
AND City.name LIKE '{3}%'
AND Employee.id = EmpLang.eid
AND EmpLang.lid = Lang.id
AND Lang.desc LIKE '{4}%'
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the root cause of the problem. You can't just throw a `DISTINCT` in front of all your problems.